# Can I use OpenSSL just to encrypt URL parameters?

Tags: iphone, encryption, openssl, public-key-encryption, url-parameters

I just need a public-key encryption scheme that I can use to encrypt parameters being sent by an iPhone app to PHP on a server.  I can't use GnuPG because of its license.

The requirements are that the app on the phone be able to communicate with the server without the user entering any credentials.  My goal here is to prevent examination of the parameters in the URL and abuse of our system through spoofing.  Thus all copies of our app in the wild can look like the same user for purposes of encryption.

I haven't been planning to use HTTPS, because (if I'm not mistaken) it needs sessions or certificates and it seems excessive (but let me know if not); I just need to encrypt and decrypt the parameter portion of the URL.

Since the data to encrypt with an RSA public key must be shorter than the key, the standard procedure is to generate a symmetric private key, encrypt that with the public key, encrypt the data with the generated private key, and then send the generated private key and the encrypted data to the server.  It looks like I have most of what I need to encrypt the generated key (except RSA_size() crashes in the process).  But I don't know how to specify and set up the encoding of the bulk data with Blowfish or some other algorithm supported by PHP.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use HTTPS to securely POST the data?

Comment: Maybe not; I don't know what's involved.  The requirements are that the app on the phone be able to communicate with the server without the user entering any credentials.  My goal here is to prevent examination of the parameters in the URL and abuse of our system through spoofing.  Thus all copies of our app in the wild can look like the same user for purposes of encryption.  I'll add this to my description above.  Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible.

You can just use the RSA pubic key cryptographic algorithms, without any of the overheads and infrastructure that PGP or X.509v3 wraps around them.

1. Generate a public-private key pair.
2. Store the private key securely on the server.  Protect it well.
3. Distribute the public key to the iPhone app.
4. The iPhone app encrypts the data using the public key.
5. The iPhone app sends the encrypted data to the server.
6. The server decrypts the encrypted data using the private key.

You can play around with this idea using the `openssl` command line tools:

On the server run:

```
$ openssl genrsa -out myprivatekey.pem 2048
$ openssl rsa -in myprivatekey.pem -pubout -out mypublickey.pem
```

Copy the mypublickey.pem to the client, and on the client create some data in data.dat and run:

```
$ openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey mypublickey.pem -in data.dat -out enc.dat
```

Send the enc.dat to the server, and then on the server run:

```
$ openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey myprivatekey.pem -in enc.data -out data2.dat
```

The public key does not have to be protected, so you can distribute it to the iPhone app in any way you want.  For example, embed it into the app, put it on a public Web server, send it to the client by insecure email. There's no problem if the bad guys get their hands on it.

Note: in the example I've created a 2048 bit RSA key.  Keep in mind that you need longer bit length keys for asymmetric algorithms (i.e. public-key algorithms) to achieve the same level of security as keys used for symmetric algorithms.  Don't go thinking that 128 bit AES encryption is very strong, so I'll just create a 128 bit RSA key -- that is way too short for an RSA key and will not give you the security strength you expect.

Now you just need to implement that by calling the openSSL libraries in code.

Comment: Thanks very much; it's just what I was looking for (although I don't know if it's better than HTTPS for my purposes).  I'll give it a shot.

Comment: If you don't know if it is any better, then it is not.

Comment: I have the OpenSSL crypto lib compiled for the phone. Now I need to do the encryption step on the phone using C code rather than command-line syntax. The data and public key will be coming from in-memory structures rather than files.

Answer (score 1):

I think, and I'm not very sure - if you need to encrypt data to send and you are not being connected via HTTPS, then you can try to implement some JS encryption module. (I have found http://www.hanewin.net/encrypt/) You can generate the keys based up on username or client pc's name.

Comment: Javascript won't be of use for an iPhone app (without some laborious workaround), and the project you linked to is encumbered by the same license that prevents me from using GnuPG.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is not to use a public/private key encryption, but to do symmetric-key encryption.  What you would probably want to do is each session have the client app generate a key, use a single HTTPS connection to send that key which the server can use to decrypt parameters.  Now all of your regular connections can just have the encrypted parameter using that key that only the client and server know.  It should be unique per device and probably session.  You might want to associate a time stamp with it, so that you know that after it has been inactive for however long it can be discarded, or seen as coming from an invalid session.

Comment: Thanks, but there aren't any sessions.  These are stand-alone queries that hit the server and return data; it's not practical (or necessary) to maintain sessions for my application.